# Include cookie in swagger doc requests

Tags: cookies, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

My web service API will check whether a certain cookie is included in the requests, but I couldn't figure out how to include a cookie to my swagger doc api calls.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Adding cookie as a editable field like this in my .yaml file.

   ```
   paths:
     /myApi/create:
       parameters:
         - name: Cookie
           in: header
           description: cookie
           required: true
           type: string
   ```
2. In the html file of swagger ui, add

   ```
   window.authorizations.add(
       "Cookie",
       new ApiKeyAuthorization("Cookie", 'Name=Val', 'header')
   )
   ```

But in both of the approach my api doesn't get the cookie, I was wondering how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

OpenAPI/Swagger spec 2.0 does not support cookie authentication. For the next version (3.0), the discussion to support it can be found in the following:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/15

UPDATE: OpenAPI spec 3.0 will support `cookie`: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.md#parameter-locations

Comment: From https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/161, it seems I can actually set cookie using "in: header". I was wondering why I couldn't do that in my approach? Btw I put the field value as "name=value", but the format should not be the problem because my api doesn't get any cookie. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is too late, but you should check the [following](https://app.swaggerhub.com/api/ponelat/with-cookies/1/edit) example:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1'
  title: With Cookie Authentication
  description: With Cookie Authentication

securityDefinitions:
  myCookie:
    type: apiKey
    name: Cookie
    in: header
paths: 
  /say-hi:
    get:
      summary: Say Hello
      description: Say Hello
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
      security:
        - myCookie: []
```

Comment: It seems the issue is that browser does not allow to set a header called cookie so easily, because of security issues:

     Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Cookie  jquery-1.8.0.min.js